# How to retrieve the current cluster name in k8s from python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I need to set my environment in my code based on kubernetes(in AKS)  cluster name in python.
I have 2 clusters stg-my-cluster, prod-my-cluster,
How can I access to this info from inside my pod?
there is a better way ?
thx

Answer (score 3):

Once you're inside the cluster, it doesn't know that it has a "name".  This only exists for management tools, such as the context name in your `.kube/config` file.

The setup I use day-to-day uses [Helm](https://helm.sh) as the primary installation mechanism, and there is a separate Helm values file per environment.  Our CD system knows how to `helm upgrade -f $CLUSTER_NAME.yaml`.  In that file we set:

```yaml
# values.prod.yaml
cluster: prod-my-cluster
```

And then you can include that as an environment variable in your Deployment:

```yaml
env:
  - name: CLUSTER
    value: {{ .Values.cluster }}
```

Once you have it in an environment variable, in Python you can access it using `os.environ`.

Comment: thanks David, but it mean maintaining 2 ( or more .yaml ) per env.

Comment: It shouldn't mean that.  We have one file per environment that has details like database host names and storage locations in addition to this `cluster` setting.

Answer (score 0):

here is a hack I found in order to get it ( not directly the cluster name, but the resourceGroup )

```
clusters = set()
config.load_incluster_config()
core = client.CoreV1Api()
configmaps = core.list_namespaced_config_map('kube-system', timeout_seconds=10)


for item in configmaps.items:
    try:
        cluster = (item.__dict__)['_data']['CLUSTER_RESOURCE_ID']
        if  cluster:
            cluster_resource_id = re.search(r"resourceGroups/([\s\S]+)/providers",cluster).group(1)
            clusters.add(cluster_resource_id)
    except:
        pass
```

In my case, I use a resourceGroup per env.
So I just have to :

```
if 'my-resource-group-production' in clusters:
    .....
```